# What is logically wrong about this VB.NET code

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have this simple VB.NET function:

```
Dim endval = Convert.ToInt16(googleXMLdocument...<s:currentItemCount>.Value) - 1
For counter = 0 To endval
  Dim seller = googleXMLdocument...<s:name>(counter).Value
  Dim containsValue = ToBeIgnored.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Ignore") = seller) 
  If containsValue Then
    Continue For
  End If
  row = GoogleResults.NewRow()
  GoogleResults.Rows.Add(row)
  GoogleResults.Rows(counter)("Seller") = seller 'sometimes this line throws an exception there is no row at position x
Next
```

In the last line I sometimes get an exception `there is no row at position x`. What could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counter variable doesn't look like it's the same as number of rows for your GoogleResults table.

I'm guessing you are looking for something like this:

```
GoogleResults.Rows(GoogleResults.Rows.Count - 1)("Seller") = seller
```

or more directly:

```
row("Seller") = seller
```

Answer (score 1):

Last two lines of the `For` loop should be rewritten like this:

```
row("Seller") = seller;
GoogleResults.Rows.Add(row)
```

Changing a row after it's added may cause unnecessary events to be fired.